# jquery form validation plugin Opera and Firefox Problem?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, cross-browser

When I try to validate my form with jQuery validator plug-in it writes the error text two times at Mozilla Firefox and Opera and doesn't erase the value of them("This field is required.") when I write suitable values for input fields. Why it writes "This field is required." error message two times and doesn't work at browser except for IE?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#courseForm").submit(function(event) {
            //$("#courseForm").validate();
            if($("#courseForm").valid()){
            var nameOfCourse = $.trim($("#course_name").val());
            var codeOfCourse = $.trim($("#course_code").val());
            var duration = $.trim($("#course_hour").val());
            var courseYear = $("#course_year").val();
            if ($("#is_elective").is(':checked')) {
                var elective = 1;
            } else {
                var elective = 0;
            }
            if ($("#is_service").is(':checked')) {
                var service = 1;
            } else {
                var service = 0;
            }
            var typeOfClassroom = $("#clasroom_type").val();
            var groupCount = $("#group_count").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: 'defineCourse.action',
                data: { pageAction:"defineCourse" , nameOfCourse: nameOfCourse, codeOfCourse: codeOfCourse, duration: duration, courseYear: courseYear, elective: elective, service: service, typeOfClassroom: typeOfClassroom, groupCount: groupCount },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == null || data == '') {
                        alert('Successfull!');
                    } else {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert('Something wrong!');
                }
            });
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

For IE, it works fine and lets accept that I didn't enter some required values. It shows the error message and if I write thar input fields it removes that text immediately but at other browser it can't.

Comment: Please don't use jQuery for validation and assume that all data sent to the server is valid. It's great for preventing stupid client requests, but it does nothing for a hacker. Its easily passed. Have simliar server logic in place too. Or just user server logic and not jQuery validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) jQuery validation plug-in then, you are totally not getting how the plug-in works! check the demo examples for how to use it, the simplest setup is:

```
$(function() {
   $("#myForm").validate();
});
```

no need for `$("#myForm").submit(...etc)` as the plug-in will take care of that!

EDIT:
Okay, so based on your update here are my comments:
First of all, All the code you added to your question now can go in the `submitHandler` method.

Secondly, do you really need to "prepare" your data before sending them? you can just use the plug-in [validation methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#List_of_built-in_Validation_methods) available and put the `pageAction` in a hidden input and your `submitHandler` will look like:

```
$("#courseForm").validate({
 rules: { // All the plug-in built-in validation methods fro your form inputs go here (e.g. required...etc)
    // ...
 },
 messages: {
   //  ...
 },
 submitHandler: function(form) {
  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: 'defineCourse.action',
   data: $(form).serialize(),
   success: function(data) {
    if (data == null || data == '') {
     alert('Successfull!');
    } else {
     alert(data);
    }
   },
   error: function(data) {
    alert('Something wrong!');
   }
  });
 }
});
```

This way make sure the form inputs have the correct `name` field expected by the page receiving the form submission (`pageAction, nameOfCourse, duration....etc`). And all the other validations (`trim`..etc) should be done server-side.

OTHERWISE, and if you want to keep doing it your way, then the code would be:

```
$("#courseForm").validate({
 rules: { // All the plug-in built-in validation methods fro your form inputs go here (e.g. required...etc)
    // ...
 },
 messages: {
   //  ...
 },
 submitHandler: function(form) {
  var nameOfCourse = $.trim($("#course_name").val());
  var codeOfCourse = $.trim($("#course_code").val());
  var duration = $.trim($("#course_hour").val());
  var courseYear = $("#course_year").val();
  var elective = 0;
  var service = 0;
  if ($("#is_elective").is(':checked')) {
   elective = 1;
  }
  if ($("#is_service").is(':checked')) {
   service = 1;
  }
  var typeOfClassroom = $("#clasroom_type").val();
  var groupCount = $("#group_count").val();
  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: 'defineCourse.action',
   data: { pageAction:"defineCourse" , nameOfCourse: nameOfCourse, codeOfCourse: codeOfCourse, duration: duration, courseYear: courseYear, elective: elective, service: service, typeOfClassroom: typeOfClassroom, groupCount: groupCount },
   success: function(data) {
    if (data == null || data == '') {
     alert('Successfull!');
    } else {
     alert(data);
    }
   },
   error: function(data) {
    alert('Something wrong!');
   }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: Hi ifaour, I know that it handles the submit function but I am posting the data after some other validation and doing  $.ajax post. Im an not using the submitting the form that's why I handle the submit and prevent the default.

Comment: Are there any other good validation plug-ins? Cos I didnt understand why it doesnt refresh the error message and erase the error message automatically after I enter correct value for an input field of that form at Firefox or Opera.

Comment: As for your second comment, this plug-in is one of the best. For your first comment, still you can do all validations within the plug-n scope! For example if you want to do more validation (not for the form inputs!!) then use that in the [submitHandler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) method where you can do ajax submit there too, check [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html). It would help us more, if you explain what are you trying to do and post more code!

Comment: Also shoul I define the rules and messages section? I didn't define it and works on IE bu at Opera of Firefox not. Maybe it causes an error, does it necessary?

Comment: No not necessary, but seriously if you're not going to use them..why using the plug-in in first place?! also for the error can you post your html code? I'm positive that the page is broken and the IE behavior is the odd one!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, basically mine had to do with some additional JavaScript that I had on the actual input fields that was preventing user to entering anything but numbers... as soon as I removed those everything start working...

Hope it helps other that may come across the same problem :)
Cheers